# Log4j configuration does not work on Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, logging

I have a problem with log4j configuration.

Before Maven packages my application in war-file, it runs tests. And log4j configuration is loaded and used - log file is created and messages are written in it and in the console.

There is log4j debug output in console:

```
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@422ede.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@422ede class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@422ede.
log4j: Using URL [file:/C:/dev/workspace/paymentsystemsstub/target/classes/log4j.properties] for automatic log4j configuration.
log4j: Reading configuration from URL file:/C:/dev/workspace/paymentsystemsstub/target/classes/log4j.properties
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[WARN, file, stdout].
log4j: Level token is [WARN].
log4j: Category root set to WARN
log4j: Parsing appender named "file".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "file".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%c] [%-5p] %n%m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "file".
log4j: Setting property [file] to [C:\tomcat\log/paymentSystemsStub.log].
log4j: Setting property [maxBackupIndex] to [1].
log4j: Setting property [maxFileSize] to [1MB].
log4j: setFile called: C:\tomcat\log/paymentSystemsStub.log, true
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Parsed "file" options.
log4j: Parsing appender named "stdout".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "stdout".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%c] [%-5p] %n%m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "stdout".
log4j: Parsed "stdout" options.
log4j: Parsing for [com.panbet.paymentstub] with value=[DEBUG].
log4j: Level token is [DEBUG].
log4j: Category com.panbet.paymentstub set to DEBUG
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.com.panbet.paymentstub=[null]
log4j: Finished configuring.
```

But when I deploy generated war-file in Tomcat, I see that log4j configuration is loaded and the log file is created, but messages are not written in it or in console:

There is log4j debug output:

```
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using context classloader WebappClassLoader
  context: /paymentstub
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@d1ad08
.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using WebappClassLoader
  context: /paymentstub
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@d1ad08
 class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using context classloader WebappClassLoader
  context: /paymentstub
  delegate: false
  repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@d1ad08
.
log4j: Using URL [file:/C:/tomcat/webapps/paymentstub/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties] for automatic log4j configuration.
log4j: Reading configuration from URL file:/C:/tomcat/webapps/paymentstub/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[WARN, file, stdout].
log4j: Level token is [WARN].
log4j: Category root set to WARN
log4j: Parsing appender named "file".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "file".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%c] [%-5p] %n%m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "file".
log4j: Setting property [file] to [C:\tomcat\log/paymentSystemsStub.log].
log4j: Setting property [maxBackupIndex] to [1].
log4j: Setting property [maxFileSize] to [1MB].
log4j: setFile called: C:\tomcat\log/paymentSystemsStub.log, true
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Parsed "file" options.
log4j: Parsing appender named "stdout".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "stdout".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%c] [%-5p] %n%m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "stdout".
log4j: Parsed "stdout" options.
log4j: Parsing for [com.panbet.paymentstub] with value=[DEBUG].
log4j: Level token is [DEBUG].
log4j: Category com.panbet.paymentstub set to DEBUG
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.com.panbet.paymentstub=[null]
log4j: Finished configuring.
```

There are files `log4j.properties` in folder `WEB-INF\classes` and `log4j-1.2.17.jar` in folder `WEB-INF\lib` (from [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j) and [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) they should be there).

I pass an absolute path where to create log file as a JVM property.

There is my `log4j.properties` file:

```
# Set root logger level to WARN and its appenders to file and stdout
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, file, stdout

# stdout is set to be a ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
# stdout uses PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%c] [%-5p] %n%m%n

# file is set to be a RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${stubLog}/paymentSystemsStub.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
# Keep one backup file
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%c] [%-5p] %n%m%n

# Print only messages of level DEBUG or above in the package com.panbet.paymentstub
log4j.logger.com.panbet.paymentstub=DEBUG
```

I am using Windows 7, Eclipse, Tomcat 7, Maven and Log4j 1.2.

I spend all day for trying to find out what's wrong and still have no idea.

**Update**

I am so confused! Turn out, that methods I invoked do not log anything! I was so sure that they do... Sorry for bother.

Comment: This is something offtopic, but why log4j? Use logback instead!

Comment: Because it is a requirement. I must use it.

Comment: @Julia Do you have any exceptions in `<TOMCAT_HOME>\logs\catalina.out`?

Comment: @Julia Then by all means this should work. Just to exclude any possibility, when you say that no messages have been logged, you have actually accessed your app so that at least a few methods that log something will get invoked, right?

Comment: @Julia Try with hardcoded logs location like this: `log4j.appender.file.File=/tmp/paymentSystemsStub.log`. Maybe the path property `stubLog` is not accessible.

Comment: @Grove Yes, of course)

Comment: Where `${stubLog}` is defined?

Comment: @MariuszS I pass this value as JVM property. And I tried with hardcoded logs location like you said - the same problem occurs. See, that's problem not only with a file - also logging in console does not work.

Comment: Where do you have your log4j.xml located in project?

Comment: @Yuriy Yunikov  Like I wrote in question "There are files `log4j.properties` in folder `WEB-INF\classes` and `log4j-1.2.17.jar` in folder `WEB-INF\lib`".  I am using Log4j 1.2 and configuring it in .properties file, not XML.

Comment: @Grove I am so confused! Turn out, that methods I invoked do not log anything! I was so sure that they do...

Comment: @Julia There you go, mystery solved :) Try adding log messages and some  "sysouts" there, to make sure you see some action. Log messages should be redirected to the specified logfile, and the sysouts to catalina.out by default. If the log messages are still missing you can doublcheck with catalina.out to see that the methods were actually invoked and doing something. Or you could also try debugging

Comment: @Grove I already did. Logging works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Steps to make Tomcat work with log4j

- We download two files from extras on tomcat download section

  tomcat-juli.jar tomcat-juli-adapters.jar
- Copy tomcat-juli.jar to $CATALINA_HOME\bin to replace old one
- Copy tomcat-juli-adapters.jar to $CATALINA_HOME\lib
- Download log4j lib and copy it to $CATALINA_HOME\libs.
- Delete logging.properties in $CATALINA_HOME\conf
- Create log4j.properties in $CATALINA_HOME\libs.
- Download log4j version greater than 1.2 and copy to
  $CATALINA_HOME\lib

After that restart tomcat.

Comment: Please don't just post a link to a blog post as an answer. Include the relevant information *here*.

Comment: $CATALINA_HOME\libs and $CATALINA_HOME\lib are used. Is it a typo? libs vs lib?

Comment: Please, also clarify what is meant by "Download log4j version greater than 1.2 and copy to $CATALINA_HOME\lib" Which file? ls -1 apache-log4j-2.0.2-bin/
log4j-1.2-api-2.0.2.jar
log4j-api-2.0.2.jar
log4j-core-2.0.2.jar
log4j-core-2.0.2-tests.jar
log4j-flume-ng-2.0.2.jar
log4j-jcl-2.0.2.jar
log4j-jmx-gui-2.0.2.jar
log4j-nosql-2.0.2.jar
log4j-slf4j-impl-2.0.2.jar
log4j-taglib-2.0.2.jar
log4j-to-slf4j-2.0.2.jar
log4j-web-2.0.2.jar

Comment: I mean download version log4j-1.2.17.jar. When i wrote this guide log4j 2 still in beta

Comment: tomcat 7-8 documentation states explicitly that these steps are only needed to configure Tomcat to use log4j for its own internal logging. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j

Answer (score -1):

@Julia Have you check your $CATALINA_BASE/conf/logging.properties file? You may need to delete it from your TOMCAT folder.

**Follow-up for my answer:**

I think your log4j.properties configuration is correct. The next step would be by checking what is the current location of the log configuration that is being loaded. Add `-Dlog4j.debug` to your `JAVA_OPTS` in `TOMCAT`. On this way you can check how the log4j is instantiated and it will show what log4j properties has been loaded. Then try to check information from the tomcat log files `catalina.out` or `catalina.2013-11-06.log`

Comment: No, this is not needed. This logging is defined on application level, not server.

Comment: @archetype I already did it. Please, read my question carefully.

Answer (score -1):

try to add this to your tomcat launcher in eclipse as JVM params

```
-Dlog4j.rootLevel="ERROR" -Dlog4j.rootAppender="console"
```

Comment: This logging is at application level.